# Wanted to null-terminate string on assembly, but got segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, memory, stack, buffer, overflow

I've read that I can allocate a String into the stack and insert other data within the allocated space, allowing relative addressing. What I've been trying to do is to allocate the string and null-terminate it, allowing the string to naturally end and include other data.

However, when I tried to assemble the code, I faced Segmentation Fault. I've used gdb to go through the code and found that "movb $al, 0x9(%rsi)" is the instruction causing segmentation fault.

Am I doing something wrong or is there other way to null-terminate the string?

Code below:

```
.text
.globl _start

_start:
   jmp MyCallStatement

   ShellCode:
      popq %rsi
      xorq %rax, %rax
      movb %al, 0x9(%rsi)
      movq %rsi, 0xa(%rsi)
      movq %rax, 0x12(%rsi)
      movb $59, %al
      movq %rsi, %rbx
      leaq 0xa(%rsi), %rcx
      leaq 0x12(%rsi), %rdx
      syscall

   MyCallStatement:
      call ShellCode
      Shellvariables:
         .ascii "/bin/bashABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCC"
```

Comment: Do you realize you didn't allocate anything on the stack? (the crash is due to you trying to write into code segment, which is probably read-only)

Answer (score 2):

What you did see in gdb are instructions in `.text` (code) section, which is highly likely read-only.

And your code does:

- jump ahead to `call` instruction, to make `call` target being ahead of `call` instruction, so the offset in the `call` opcode is negative, to avoid zero bytes in the resulting machine code (to make the whole exploit code zero-free, thus it may work as null terminated string, containing only 1-255 byte values).
- `call` back (negative offset in call opcode), this will push on stack address of the first byte after `call` instruction, which is first letter of the data string.
- `pop rsi` -> loads address of string into `rsi` -> keep in mind this is pointing still into the code segment, into your original data
- `xor %eax,%eax` is enough to set `rax` to zero, you can save 1 byte here
- `movb %al, 0x9(%rsi)` tries to modify code segment byte -> crash

What your code is missing is after `pop %rsi`, when you have address of your string data, you need to allocate stack space, like:

```
sub   $64, %rsp
; then copy the original string data there (9 chars needed in this case)
movq  (%rsi),%rax  ; load 8 characters of string into rax
movq  %rax,(%rsp)  ; store it to the temporarily allocated stack space
movl  8(%rsi),%eax ; load 4 more characters of string into eax
movl  %eax,8(%rsp) ; store it to the temporarily allocated stack space
; null terminate the COPY of the string (in the stack, where you can write)
xorl  %eax,%eax    ; rax = 0
movb  %al,9(%rsp)  ; make the stack copy of string null terminated
```

And after that use `rsp` as address of string, not `rsi`... I'm actually not sure what the remaining instructions were supposed to do, but as you are using gdb and know your idea, you can sort it out on your own. :)

---

edit: don't forget to restore the stack later, if you want to return to the caller... like `add $64, %rsp` or if `rbp` contains stack frame, then `leave` may be enough, etc...

edit2: I had to fix the code, as it is actually 9 characters long string, so two `mov` used to copy it.

Also I didn't check the machine code, whether I introduced some zero byte by accident, if yes, then you have to use different instruction to achieve the same result. As long as you are just learning + debugging initial version of exploit, make sure the code is correct first, and working, then check the machine code and find replacement code for any accidental zero value.

Comment: Thanks so much! I realised what I misunderstood now. I wasn't playing with the stack's addressing to the string. I was actually playing with the return address (which the string has been allocated next to) and editing the code segment.

However, I saw this working in a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XTmLamRonE). Not sure if you know the reason why it worked for him but not me?

Comment: Alternatively, is there any way to edit memory in the code segment?

Comment: @SamuelPua the whole `jmp + call + string + pop` trick is an idiom how to extract address of data while having PIC code, which IMO in x86-64 is needlessly convoluted ported 32bit version, as in x86-64 you can probably simply use relative addressing, i.e. `lea rsi,[rel Shellvariables]` (NASM syntax, don't know how to write it in AT&T) would maybe work. In 32 bit the `pop` of return address was simpler way, how to figure out where your code landed.

Comment: @Telboon you can call appropriate OS service calls to change the memory mapping to allow for code segment writes... I'm sorry, but I can't provide any details, as I never did any exploit coding, nor I'm interested into it, so I'm barely gliding on the surface of the specialized knowledge, I can explain you only these absolute basics like why the `jmp+call+pop` was used, and why it does crash, but I have no idea what true exploits do, and I just hope you are learning it for white-hat purposes too... There's enough unintentional bugs in SW already, people are crazy by adding intentional exploits

Comment: @Telboon you can also probably use some compile/linking time switches to produce vulnerable binary which reports to the OS as requiring write access into code segment (again I'm just guessing from the comments I have ever seen in other questions). All of this should be described in some high quality resources dedicated to exploit writing, so if you are into it, I expect you to do your research and study... can't help more, as I don't want to waste my time with this stuff.

Comment: @Telboon And the video is 32bit related, so as in this case, it's probably teaching you things not needed in 64b. (but the more you know, the better, but if tutorial is 32b, you should rather use 32 bit, than converting it to 64b yourself, unless you are skilled enough in assembly to manage such conversions mostly correctly and debug the remaining issues yourself) ... but such conversion is not completely trivial, 32b vs 64b are different platforms. They may feel familiar at first due to almost all instructions being same, but there will be several "gotchas" moments if you think they're "same"

Comment: Gotcha. Good stuff. Wish I can upvote you 10 times (but I can't even do once cos of my low reputation). Appreciate your help man!

Comment: This is a bit off-topic. But what are the `movl` and `movb` instructions? I checked intel manual and found only `movq`.

Comment: @St.Antario it's AT&T syntax with `<instruction><size_suffix>` -> `movl  8(%rsi),%eax` = `mov eax, dword [rsi+8]` (NASM syntax).  ... and more tricky example `movzbl (%rsi),%eax` = `movzx eax, byte [rsi]` (which has <size1><size2> two suffixes (source -> target)).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author).*

Ped7g solved my question. Below is my final code:

```
.text
.globl _start

_start:
   jmp MyCallStatement

   ShellCode:
      popq %rsi

      # Code from StackOverflow

      sub $64, %rsp
      movq (%rsi), %rax
      movq %rax, (%rsp)

      movq 8(%rsi), %rax
      movq %rax, 8(%rsp)

      movq %rsp, %rsi

      xorq %rax, %rax

      # End Code from StackOverflow

      xorq %rax, %rax
      movb %al, 0x9(%rsi)
      movq %rsi, 0xa(%rsi)
      movq %rax, 0x12(%rsi)
      movb $59, %al
      movq %rsi, %rdi
      leaq 0xa(%rsi), %rsi
      leaq 0x12(%rsi), %rdx
      syscall

      jmp Exit

   MyCallStatement:
      call ShellCode
      Shellvariables:
         .ascii "/bin/bashABBBBBBBBCCCCCCCC"

   Exit:
      xorq %rax, %rax
      xorq %rbx, %rbx
      movb $1, %al
      int $0x80
```